# If-less 1 or 0 resolution in jQuery

Tags: jquery, math, logic

I wish to make any number other than 160 resolve to 1, and 160 resolve to 0. 160 must resolve to exactly 1, no more, no less. Does anybody know how to do this? I don't want to use an if or else, but I'm fine with using modulus and math.abs. Thanks.

CLARIFICATION: no ternary operators, I'm looking for more of a mathematical operation, or something ingenuitive like that.

Comment: Clarify "if or else" or "conditionals/branching", or you're going to get a **lot** of answers that you do not want.

Comment: Nothing that worked, I've looked at using modulus and also Math.abs(), unfortunately, while making 160 resolve to 1 is quite trivial, making any number n resolve to 0 with the same algorithm is proving challenging.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not strictly mathematical operations, you can use the javascript `Math` object's functions `max` and `min` to do this.

To get `n` to resolve to 1 for 160, and 0 otherwise, you can use:

```
var r = Math.abs(Math.max(-1, Math.min(1, n - 160))) ;
```

If you want the 1 and 0 reversed, you can do:

```
var r1 = Math.abs(r - 1) ;
```

Comment: I'm actually getting the opposite result from your code: 0 for 160 and 1 otherwise.  However, after using the clever line: Math.abs(r-1), it works as intended.  +1

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks! (Side question: the Javascript Math library probably uses if statements, doesn't it?)

Answer (score 8):

*(Note, this was before the edit)*

Ternary operator (it's neither `if` nor `else` ;)):

```
var value = number === 160 ? 0 : 1;
```

---

Still not math but *type conversion*:

```
var value = +(number !== 160);
```

Still not math but *boolean operators*:

```
var value = (number !== 160) && 1 || 0;
```

A *little bit* math and *type conversion*:

```
var value = +(!!(160 - number)); // outer brackets can probably be omitted
```

*maybe I should stop now ;)*

Comment: While I like this answer, I forgot to specify I'm looking for more of a mathematical operation. I love the answer though, so you get an upvote :)

Comment: That's really neat, if I could +2 you I would, Gus gave me more of what I was looking for though, thanks.

Comment: @Vap0r: No worries, I'm just having fun finding other ways ;) Just ignore me :D